# Experience Analytics page conflict with Glass Mapper

Tags: experience-analytics, glass-mapper

I'm getting the following error message when I go to Experience Analytics from the dashboard in 9.0.2 (rev. 180604). We are using Glass Mapper elsewhere in the application, but there's no customization of the CMS

[image: Error message]

Here's a snippet of the problematic Sitecore file:

```razor
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@using Sitecore
@using Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client
@using Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Extensions
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.Renderings
@using Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.Texts
@using Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.UserControls
@using Globals = Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Globals
@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
@{
    var rendering = Html.Sitecore().Controls().GetUserControl(Model.Rendering);
    rendering.Class = "sc-DateRangeFilter";
    rendering.Requires.Script("client", "DateRangeFilter.js");
    rendering.Attributes.Add("data-bind", "visible: isVisible");
    rendering.HasNestedComponents = true;

    var errorMessages = new
    {
        InvalidDate = Helper.GetTextValue(Globals.System.Texts.ErrorMessages.InvalidDate)
    };

    rendering.Attributes.Add("data-sc-errortexts", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorMessages));
    rendering.Attributes.Add("data-sc-serverdate", DateUtil.ToServerTime(DateTime.UtcNow).ToDashedDateRangeFormat());
    rendering.Attributes.Add("data-sc-defaultdaterangeoffset-from", Config.DefaultDateRangeOffsetFrom.ToString());
    rendering.Attributes.Add("data-sc-defaultdaterangeoffset-to", Config.DefaultDateRangeOffsetTo.ToString());
}
```

It's complaining about: *Config.DefaultDateRangeOffsetFrom.ToString()*

I know I could probably track down the intended namespace and add it to the code, but is there a solution that doesn't involve changing Sitecore-owned files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have a global namespace declared in your Web.config

Check your Web.config for the namespace *Glass.Mapper.Sc*.

You shouldn't need to have a namespace for this in your root Web.config and these should be configured in the views folder.